# How to read a line from stdin

Tags: c

I am trying to read a text line from user but the `fgets` wont work right after the `printf("Enter a string:");` the program terminates and doesn't give a chance to enter anything.

```
fgets(string, 100, stdin)
```

Comment: Some code could be helpful.

Comment: ever tried scanf("%[^\n]",aaa) ; where aaa is your char variable

Comment: My debugging crystal ball tells me `string` is declared as `char *string;` (which is all I have to go on since you posted "code" that doesn't compile). Consider providing a real char buffer and not just an indeterminate pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it:

```
char mystr[100];
if ( fgets (mystr, 100 , stdin) != NULL ) {
    puts (mystring);
}
```

You need to `#include <stdio.h>` in order for this to compile.

The first pointer must point to a memory block of enough size to fit the number of characters passed in the second pointer.

Comment: `sizeof(mystr)` instead of hardcoding the value `100` in the function call?